# How to write inline code with semiverbatim in beamer

Tags: beamer, code

I use semiverbatim to write code block, now I want to use the same format to write inline code, how can I do this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{semiverbatim}
            while true:
                task = GetNewTask(tasks)
                handle(task)
    \end{semiverbatim} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out, should use `\semiverbatim{code}`.